# Drop-down clicked, a form created

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bYlaq.png)
This error message keeps opening on console.
And I am using Ember.js

I am trying to make a drop-down and whenever on option from a drop-down is clicked, a form should be made based on what an option is chosen. For example, there are 3 options on dropdown: name, text, drop-down. When a user click a text, a text form should be created below. I already made an dropdown and tried to implement by writing document.write(" < /h1>"), but it keeps saying uncaught syntax error. Can someone help me please?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function clicking(option) {
        if (option === "name")
            //document.write("<h1>Hello<h1>");
    }
</script>

<h1>Data Form Test</h1>
<div id="dropdown">
    <form>
        <select id="selectBox" onchange="clicking(this)">
            <option value="" disabled="disabled" selected="selected" style="display:none">Please select a option</option>
            <option value="name">Name</option>
            <option value="title">Title</option>
            <option value="text">Text</option>
            <option value="check-box">Check-box</option>
            <option value="drop-down">Drop-down</option>
            <option value="calendar">Calendar</option>
        </select>
    </form>
</div>

<div id="div1"></div>
```

Comment: because, you have missed double quote `if (option === "name)`

Comment: Still I got an error message on console....

Comment: See my updated answer, check "Run code snippet". You can't access your option value just by using `option`. You should use `option.value` instead. Debug your function using `console.log()`.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function clicking(option) {
        if (option == "name"){
            //document.write("<h1>Hello<h1>");
        }
    }
</script>
```

**and on html**

```
onchange="clicking(this.value)"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't access your selected value via `option`, you need to use property `value` instead. In my example I changed `option` with `event`.

To write some HTML/text into div/selector use `.innerHTML` method instead of `document.write`.

See working example.

```js
    function clicking(event) {
        if (event.value === "name")
            document.getElementById('div1').innerHTML = "<h1>Hello<h1>";
    }
```

```html
<h1>Data Form Test</h1>
<div id="dropdown">
    <form>
        <select id="selectBox" onchange="clicking(this)">
            <option value="" disabled="disabled" selected="selected" style="display:none">Please select a option</option>
            <option value="name">Name</option>
            <option value="title">Title</option>
            <option value="text">Text</option>
            <option value="check-box">Check-box</option>
            <option value="drop-down">Drop-down</option>
            <option value="calendar">Calendar</option>
        </select>
    </form>
</div>

<div id="div1"></div>
```

If you would like to use your `form` to perform for example an `ajax` request. Here is another example I created for you.

I used `addEventListener` to show to different approach of handling your `clicking` function.

Read my comments.

```js
// Our selectors
var form = document.getElementById('example-form');
var select = document.getElementById('selectBox');
var result = document.getElementById('result');

// Let's add an event listener to our form, we will listen whenever we submit the form
form.addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
  
  var elements = this.querySelectorAll('input, select');
  
  var formData = {};
  
  for(i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    var element = elements[i];
    
    Object.assign(formData, { [element.name] : element.value })
  }
  
  console.log(formData);
  
  // Now you can perform some ajax call eg.
  // I've commented it out, but code works, you just need to replace url
  //$.ajax({
  //  url: 'http://example.com/action/url/',
  //  type: 'post',
  //  data: formData, // our form data
  //  success: function(response) {
  //    result.innerHTML = response;
  //  }
  //})

  // Prevent Page from autoreloading
  e.preventDefault();
  return false;
});


// Another approach of handling your clicking function is by passing eventListener to select
select.addEventListener('change', function(e) {
  // Log
  //console.log(e.target.value);
  // We can use switch here for example
  // Code becomes more readable
  switch (e.target.value) {
    case 'name':
    case 'title':
    case 'text':
      result.innerHTML = '<h1>Hello ' + e.target.value + '</h1>';
      
    default:
      break;
  }
});
```

```html
   <form id="example-form">
        <select id="selectBox" name="selectBox">
            <option value="" disabled="disabled" selected="selected" style="display:none">Please select a option</option>
            <option value="name">Name</option>
            <option value="title">Title</option>
            <option value="text">Text</option>
            <option value="check-box">Check-box</option>
            <option value="drop-down">Drop-down</option>
            <option value="calendar">Calendar</option>
        </select>
        <input name="example1" value="" placeholder="example input 1" />
        <input name="example2" value="" placeholder="example input 2" />
        <button type="submit">Submit me</button>
    </form>
    
    
<div id="result"></div>
```